# How default .equals and .hashCode will work for my classes?

Tags: java, object, equals, hashcode, equality

Say I have my own class

```
public class MyObj { /* ... */ }
```

It has some attributes and methods. It DOES NOT implement equals, DOES NOT implement hashCode.

Once we call equals and hashCode, what are the default implementations? From Object class? And what are they? How the default equals will work? How the default hashCode will work and what will return? == will just check if they reference to the same object, so it's easy, but what about equals() and hashCode() methods?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yes, the default implementation is Object's (generally speaking; if you inherit from a class that redefined equals and/or hashCode, then you'll use that implementation instead).

From the documentation:

[`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence    relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns
> true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

[`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

> As far as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object returns distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Comment: Mind that contrary to `hashCode`'s documentation, HotSpot [returns a random number per default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237720/what-is-an-objects-hash-code-if-hashcode-is-not-overridden/32454673#32454673) as the hash. See also [this blog entry](https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/java/openjdk/biased-locking/2017/01/30/hashCode.html).

Answer (score 62):

From [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) in one of the JVM implementations:

```java
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    return this == object;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return VMMemoryManager.getIdentityHashCode(this);
}
```

In both cases it's just comparing the memory addresses of the objects in question.

Comment: What version of JDK it from? In `v6u23 ea`: `public native int hashCode();`

Comment: @kha - You're right, I think I tracked down one of the native implementations to see what it actually did

Comment: "In both cases it's just comparing the memory addresses of the objects in question.": HotSpot [returns a random number per default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237720/what-is-an-objects-hash-code-if-hashcode-is-not-overridden/32454673#32454673) as the hash. See also [this blog entry](https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/java/openjdk/biased-locking/2017/01/30/hashCode.html).

Answer (score 12):

There are default implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Object. If you don't provide your own implementation, those will be used. For `equals()`, this means an `==` comparison: the objects will only be equal if they are exactly the same object. For `hashCode()`, the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) has a good explanation.

For more information, see Effective Java, [Chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) (pdf), item 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from `Object` class since your class extends Object implicitly. `equals` simply returns `this == obj`. `hashCode` implementation is native. Just a guess - it returns the pointer to the object.

Comment: It is a pointer to the object located in memory, but it's not a memory address of the object. The GC can move the object around in memory and the hash code will remain the same.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427631/how-is-hashcode-calculated-in-java may be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide your own implementation, one derived from Object would be used. It is OK, unless you plan to put your class instances into i.e. HashSet (any collection that actually use hashCode() ), or something that need to check object's equality (i.e. HashSet's contains() method). Otherwise it will work incorrectly, if that's what you are asking for.

It is quite easy to provide your own implementation of these methods thanks to [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: (a) Why do you say the Object class’ default implementation of ‘equals’ will not work correctly with HashSet? That contradicts the other answers on this page. (b) Thanks for the Commons Lang links.

Comment: @Basil: I don't think that contradicts. Of course default implementation would work... somehow, but not the way you expect. That is, since equals() uses reference equality, two otherwise identical objects would be "different" in the eyes of default implementation. As the result, you might end up having two different instances of the exactly same thing in your Set. And rather typical use of Sets is when you want to eliminate duplicates...

Comment: @PawełDyda: The default behavior is generally correct for mutable types.  If `Foo` and `Bar` are references to two different instances of a mutable type, and there exists a method (e.g. `SomeMutatingMethod`) such that `Foo.SomeMutatingMethod()` does not affect `Bar` the same way it does `Foo`, that difference should be sufficient to regard the objects as unequal.

Answer (score 0):

IBM's [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html) says:

> Under this default implementation, two
>   references are equal only if they
>   refer to the exact same object.
>   Similarly, the default implementation
>   of hashCode() provided by Object is
>   derived by mapping the memory address
>   of the object to an integer value.

However, to be sure of the exact implementation details for a particular vendor's Java version it's probably best to look as the source (if it's available)