# Comparing the content of two objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, equals

I tried to perform a comparison between two objects of the same class. Actually, I wanted to compare the content of the both the objects. Here, the objects are of class Student. In class Student I have overridden the `equals()` method as shown below.
By doing so, will my intention be accomplished (compare the names and birthdays of both students)? If not what is happening here?
The problem is that I don't get the answer I expect. The output is `false` even though it must be `true`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student("John", "Johnny");
        Student b = new Student("John", "Johnny");
        a.setBirthDate(10, 10, 10);
        b.setBirthDate(10, 10, 10);
        boolean ans = Student.equals(a, b);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

}
```

```
public class Date {
    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;
    
    public Date(int d, int m, int y) {
        this.day = d;
        this.month = m;
        this.year = y;
    }
}
```

```
public class Student{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public void setBirthDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        Date b_day = new Date(day, month, year);
        birthDate = b_day;
    }
}


@Override
    public boolean equals(Object student) {
        System.out.println(this.firstName);
        System.out.println(this.lastName);
        System.out.println(this.birthDate);
        
        System.out.println(((Student)student).firstName);
        System.out.println(((Student)student).lastName);
        System.out.println(((Student)student).birthDate);
        return super.equals(student);
        
    }
```

I have overridden the equals method as follows. But still I face the same issue. I suspect that there's something wrong with the `Date` class. But the problem is that I'm not quite sure of it. Also, I don't understand how to remedy the problem. Can someone please tell me what's wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is you overwrote `equals`, but didn't add any additional checks. Currently, it just prints the values of each object. The line `return super.equals(student);` is equivalent to not overriding the method in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure your equals method similarly to an if statement. You just need to cast the other argument first before your can compare their fields.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Check if the other object is also a Student
    if (o instanceof Student) {
        // Now that we know o is a student, we can safely cast it
        Student other = (Student) o;

        // Similarly to how you would write an if statement you can compare each individual field.
        // Thanks to inheritance, we defer the equality check of each field to its own implementation
        return this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)
            && this.lastName.equals(other.lastName)
            && this.birthDate.equals(other.birthDate);
    }

    // Other object was not a student
    return false;
}
```

You then need to go write something similar in `Date` so that when you compare `birthDate`, it will know what to do.

You can also take this one step farther by using `Objects.equals(a, b)` instead of `a.equals(b)`. This will ensure you do not get a nullPointerException if `a` happens to be null when comparing them. However, since this looks to be a school project I imagine you may be expected to either check manually or assume the values will not be null instead of using the standard library.

Comment: Actually, its better to use `Objects.equals` incase of `null` possibility. Further `hashCode` is needed for `equals` to work. `hashCode` is uber requirement and `equals` as the granular requirement. `hashCode` identifies the `bucket` and `equals` checks for equality within the identified bucket.

Comment: @HorseAlso while `hashCode` is important, it is in no way needed for `equals` to function. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4179023/5987669
It sounds like you are describing `hashCode`'s usage in a `HashMap`. While it is necessary for a hashmap to function correctly, it is not necessary for direct comparisons.
Also, I mentioned `Objects.equals` in the second paragraph, but left it out of the code sample to make it easier to read for a beginner and highlight the usage of inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for pointing about `Objet.equals` in your explanation. Apologies, i missed it. Yes, i was talking about `HashMap` and it's derivative like `ConcurrentHashMap`. It is recommended to override `hashCode`  as we can't control the usage of our class by others. So, it is better to seal the class with possibly known good practices to avoid future issues.

Answer (score 0):

For `equals` to work, you need to override `hashCode` also. Further equality check needs actual comparison of your objects.

Also, any related objects also has to implement `hashCode` and `equals` method. In this case `Date`.

### Possible code

```java
import java.util.Objects;

class Date {

    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;

    public Date(int d, int m, int y) {
        this.day = d;
        this.month = m;
        this.year = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Date date = (Date) o;
        return day == date.day &&
            month == date.month &&
            year == date.year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(day, month, year);
    }
}

public class Student {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Student("John", "Johnny", new Date(10, 10, 10))
            .equals(new Student("John", "Johnny", new Date(10, 10, 10))));
        System.out.println(new Student("John", "Johnny", new Date(11, 10, 10))
            .equals(new Student("John", "Johnny", new Date(10, 10, 10))));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return Objects.equals(firstName, student.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, student.lastName) &&
            Objects.equals(birthDate, student.birthDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, birthDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing `hashCode` will have no effect on the functionality of `equals`. It defaults to comparing the object address (Ex: `this == other`). Implementing `hashCode` would only work if it compared hashes, but it would still be unreliable due to potential hash collisions.

Comment: Just edit your `equals` method to use getters, as the variables are private.

Comment: Since it is a local method it is able to access private members directly. I would recommend avoiding the getters unless there is some functionality you might miss out on.

Comment: @AP11, actually this is will be an interesting discussion to have. Generally i prefer using `private` fields inside `hashCode` and `equals` as it resembles the `actual state` rather than a `view`. getters provide a `view`. But if `view` is the expectation, then even the `hashCode` should use the `view`. Otherwise there will be discrepancy in some use cases(say map). As @Locke mentioned, i will also recommend to use attributes directly always (with no exception :) ).