# Removing elements of one list if present in another list using stream

Tags: java, java-stream, remove-if

I didn't find any thread here on this Question. I am trying to Remove elements (Cars in my case) of one list (cars1) if present in another list (cars2) using java stream.
I tried using removeIf but then it felt like it works more appropriately with List of Strings, etc.

```
    Car c1 = new Car();
    c1.id = 1;
    c1.name = "C1";

    Car c2 = new Car();
    c2.id = 2;
    c2.name = "C2";

    List<Car> cars1 = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars1.add(c1);
    cars1.add(c2);

    List<Car> cars2 = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars2.add(c2);

    // TODO : Remove all the cars from cars1 list that are in cars2 list using java streams
```

Comment: Are methods `hashCode` / `equals` implemented properly in class `Car`?

Comment: `cars1.removeAll(cars2);`

Comment: Why streams? `List.removeAll` and `List.removeIf` are way more suitable for the task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If methods `hashCode` and `equals` are properly implemented in class `Car`, the stream-based solutions may look as follows:

- filter out the values, collect into a new list

```java
// Predicate.not added in Java 11
List<Car> notJava11 = cars1.stream()
                        .filter(Predicate.not(cars2::contains))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Car> notIn2 = cars1.stream()
                        .filter(car -> !cars2.contains(car))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- Use `forEach` for `cars2` (affecting `cars1`):

```java
cars2.forEach(cars1::remove); 
// no need to call cars2.stream().forEach(cars1::remove);
```

Here the first occurrence of Car instance is removed in `cars1`

- `removeIf` should work also

```java
cars1.removeIf(cars2::contains);
```

---

If you due to some reason `equals`/`hashCode` are not overridden in class `Car`, the following solution may be offered:

```java
List<Car> notIn2 = cars1
        .stream()
        .filter(c1 -> cars2
            .stream()
            .noneMatch(c2 -> 
                 c1.getId() == c2.getId()
                 && Objects.equals(c1.getName(), c2.getName())
            )
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- `removeIf`:

```java
cars1.removeIf(c1 -> cars2
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(c2 -> c1.getId() == c2.getId() 
        && Objects.equals(c1.getName(), c2.getName())
    )
);
```

Comment: What if hashCode and equals are not properly implemented or the objects in Cars1 list and cars2 list are not the same but their values (id and name) are same

Comment: In your example the same instance `c2` is added to both lists so in such case removal takes place successfully.  But assuming that a new object `c2_1` is created instead having the same field values `Car c2_1 = new Car(2, "C2");` -- with default implementation of `equals` `c2.equals(c2_1)` returns `false` because these are [different references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178997/how-default-equals-and-hashcode-will-work-for-my-classes)

Comment: True. c2.equals(c2_1) returns false, but what if we want to compare elements (id and name) and then decide if the elements match then car object should be removed from the list?

Comment: @Tiya, you may check the update

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply by using removeAll() method. You have to implement hashcode and equals in Car class.
Then you can `cars1.removeAll(cars2);`. this statement would leave only c1 in cars1 list.