# What is the code used by the Java Set to generate the hashcode?

Tags: java, hashcode

I can't seem to find it. What is it? THANKS!

Comment: No, the underlying code;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is hashCode() calculated in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427631/how-is-hashcode-calculated-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Set does not generate any hashcodes. It depends on hashcodes defined for the objects put into the Set.

Any class can override public int hashCode().

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the source for `Object`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html) you can see this is done in native code. The `Set` interface just calls `hashCode()` on the objects in the set.

Answer (score 1):

As "[Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html)" is just an interface, the hashcode will be generated by the actual implementation you're using, e.g. [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashSet.html) or [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TreeSet.html) (or actually, [AbstractSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/AbstractSet.html)).

Comment: Bhesh - you're probably right - though I guess there were 2 different ways to read the question:  The hash code generation of the Set itself, or how the Set generates hashcodes for its objects - the later of which would only be applicable if using HashSet, which isn't mentioned.  Maybe the OP can clarify the request?

Comment: Your point absolutely makes sense. Problem is with the OP's body which is not even the half of the title itself.