# Object.hashCode() algorithm

Tags: java, hashcode, pseudocode

I'm looking for the algorithm of **Object.hashCode()**.

This code is native in [**Object.java**](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html).

Is this because

(a) the code is in assembly-- 
never was in Java or any other HLL at all

or

(b) it simply isn't disclosed

?

In either case, I am looking to get hold of the algorithm (pseudo-code or some detailed explanation) of "how **hashCode()** is calculated"-- what are the params going into its calculation and the calculation itself?

Please note: It's the [**hashCode()** of **Object**](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode)  i'm looking for-- 
not another like that of **String** or **hashMap/table**.

//==========================================================================

the [new Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)-- jdk 8 now saying

```
"The value returned by hashCode() is the object's hash code, which is the object's memory address in hexadecimal."
```

Comment: I believe that it is native because the hashCode of Object is a memory address identifier, not actually a hash of the fields of the object.

Comment: Someone needs to update the docs you are quoting. Because it is completely wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Native `hashCode` method implementation depends on the `JVM`. By default in HotSpot it returns random number, you can check it in the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp) (function `get_next_hash`)

Answer (score 9):

Despite the Javadoc, the algo only may use the address as an input.  This means that even though new objects use the same address in eden space they won't have the same hashCode.

There is a number of algos it might be using and not all use the address.

Note: the hashCode() is 31-bit.

BTW You can set it with `Unsafe.putInt(object, 1, value)`on Hotspot.

```
Set<Integer> ints = new LinkedHashSet<>();
int negative = 0, nonneg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.gc();
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        int h = new Object().hashCode();
        ints.add(h);
        if (h < 0) negative++;
        else nonneg++;
    }
}
System.out.println("unique: " + ints.size() + " negative: " + negative + " non-neg: " + nonneg);
```

prints

```
unique: 10000 negative: 0 non-neg: 10000
```

Using Unsafe

```
Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);

Object o = new Object();
System.out.println("From header " + Integer.toHexString(unsafe.getInt(o, 1L)));
// sets the hashCode lazily
System.out.println("o.hashCode()  " + Integer.toHexString(o.hashCode()));
// it's here now.
System.out.println("after hashCode() From header " + Integer.toHexString(unsafe.getInt(o, 1L)));
unsafe.putInt(o, 1L, 0x12345678);
System.out.println("after change o.hashCode()  " + Integer.toHexString(o.hashCode()));
```

prints

```
From header 0
o.hashCode()  2260e277
after hashCode() From header 2260e277
after change o.hashCode()  12345678
```

Comment: "hashCode() using only the address of the object" would be consistent w/the specs at http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode. but then youre saying "even though new objects use the same address, they won't have the same hashCode". how then is this tie broken? some other memory location than the object's reference address (like that of some member, the ending address/amount of memory it uses, some stuff on the timestamp...?)

Comment: although meets "same hashCode for same object at every call of hashCode() within one execution", solely the address of the object for this calculation doesn`t feel so right-- too consistent with memory space, not that strong on randomness of hashcode.

Comment: it would be an immutable "handle" identifier that would remain constant for the lifetime of the object. Most likely VM implementation dependent and will likely not have any relationship to the memory address, because due to GC operations all objects in java are relocatable in physical memory.

Comment: @peterk I believe in a very early version, objects could not be moved and indeed the address was part of the hash. (before Java 1.2)

Comment: likely in the past as it was easy to implement, but surely not the case today or proper.  The only thing appropriate to assume is that it is invariant during the lifespan of the object and unique amongst all objects in the VM instance.

Comment: The hashCode is not unique among the instances in the VM. See comments on [this answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427655/1048186)

Comment: @JosiahYoder You only need about 64K objects for it to be likely that two of them to have the same randomly generated hashCode.

Comment: Yes, I found in [my experiments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427631/how-is-hashcode-calculated-in-java/2427655#2427655) it took on average about 80,000 newly created objects to get a collision. This is a purely experimental result. I don't know the theory, but I'm surprised a 32-bit number can only index 64k objects. Are only 16 bits actually used?

Answer (score 2):

`hashCode` is a native method, which means that a system library is called internally. This is because of the reason that hashcode internally will try to generate a number depending on the object memory location. This code is machine dependent and probably written in C.

But if you are really interested to see the native code, then follow this:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/e947a98ea3c1/src/share/native/java/

Comment: Well, thats the thing-- is object memory location the only param to go into hashCode() calculation? how's it done-- on the lower-end bits of the address maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It's because it relies on low-level details that aren't exposed to Java code. Some basic parts of the standard library (like `java.lang.Object`) must be implemented in native code.

As an aside, you can find at least one [interesting article](http://blogs.tedneward.com/2008/07/16/ObjecthashCode+Implementation.aspx) that does into more detail about the HotSpot implementation.