# What precisely is the algorithm used by java.lang.Object's hashCode

Tags: java

What is the algorithm used in the ***`JVM`*** to implement `java.lang.Object`'s implicit `hashCode()` method?

[***`OpenJDK`*** or ***`Oracle JDK`*** are preferred in the answers].

Comment: @PM77-1 probably fact that this is `native` method and not many people know where to look for its implementation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977495/java-object-hashcode-algorithm - which has links to the native source. However, after reading the source I am even more confused.

Comment: It should be noted that the hashcode algorithms for other objects are all over the map.  String, last I looked, uses a hash of the first N characters of the string data.  Container objects will use some sort of sum of the hashes of the contained objects.

Comment: Duly noted. I understand, but I'm still curious about object in particular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's implementation dependant (and heavily so, the algorithm is *entirely* up to the implementation, as long as it's consistent.) However, as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977495/java-object-hashcode-algorithm), you can see the [native source file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp) where the hash is generated in OpenJDK 7 (look at the `get_next_hash()` function), which actually specifies a number of possible algorithms in this particular release:

```
// Possibilities:
// * MD5Digest of {obj,stwRandom}
// * CRC32 of {obj,stwRandom} or any linear-feedback shift register function.
// * A DES- or AES-style SBox[] mechanism
// * One of the Phi-based schemes, such as:
//   2654435761 = 2^32 * Phi (golden ratio)
//   HashCodeValue = ((uintptr_t(obj) >> 3) * 2654435761) ^ GVars.stwRandom ;
// * A variation of Marsaglia's shift-xor RNG scheme.
// * (obj ^ stwRandom) is appealing, but can result
//   in undesirable regularity in the hashCode values of adjacent objects
//   (objects allocated back-to-back, in particular).  This could potentially
//   result in hashtable collisions and reduced hashtable efficiency.
//   There are simple ways to "diffuse" the middle address bits over the
//   generated hashCode values
//
```

As already stated, the default algorithm is to simply go with a random number, however an interesting comment further down states:

```
// Marsaglia's xor-shift scheme with thread-specific state
// This is probably the best overall implementation -- we'll
// likely make this the default in future releases.
```

This is similar to the `(obj ^ stwRandom)` approach mentioned in the above list of possibilities, but it gets around the unwanted regularities associated with objects allocated quickly in succession by tying "thread-specific state" information into the hash also - so if two objects happened to be allocated at a very similar time due to them being allocated on two separate threads executing simultaneously, the discrete threading information fed into the hash should still ensure discrete enough hashes will be generated.