# what is difference between object value and object hashCode value

Tags: java

```
class RefDem
{
    public void m1()
    {
      System.out.println("m1() method....");
    }
}
class RefDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
   //d is object of RefDem class
    RefDem d=new RefDem();
    d.m1();
   System.out.println("d :"+d);
  System.out.println("d hash code :"+d.hashCode());
}
}
```

**output:**

```
m1() Mehtod
d : RefDem@1e5e2c3  //please explain what is this value
d hash code : 31843011   //please explain what is this
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer for it can be found in any manual or even javadocs

Comment: Just read :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is hashCode() calculated in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427631/how-is-hashcode-calculated-in-java)

Comment: You should take a look at [code of `toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Object.java?av=f#235) method from `Object` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not override `toString` and `hashValue`, so the implementations from `Object` are used.

`toString()` returns a String consisting of the class name (`RefDem`) and the memory location in hexadecimal form (`1e5e2c3`) seperated by "@".

`"d :" + d` is equivalent to `"d :" + d.toString()` so you get `"d :RefDem@1e5e2c3"`

The `hashCode` implementation of Object returns the memory location of the Object (as int) which is `31843011` (note that `31843011 == 0x1E5E2C3`)

Answer (score 0):

The first is the standard output for the `toString()` method. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

The second is the [hashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) for this object.