# hashCode() method uses class to calculate the hashcode?

Tags: hashcode

During an interview, interviewer asked me - is the hashcode calculated based on Class?

I told him, hashcode will be calculated based on the fields or variables in the class. He gave me some expression which makes me think like the answer is wrong.

I read the java doc but I didn't get the clear idea. I read the post [how is hascode calculated in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427631/how-is-hashcode-calculated-in-java) In that there is Integer hashcode and Character hashcode. Could anyone tell me how the hashcode for a particular object will be calculated and what is Interger hashcode and String hashcode?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "hashCode() method uses class to calculate the hashcode?". If you look at the signature of the `Object.hashCode()` method, you'll realize that

1. It is an instance method that any Java class can override.
2. If a class (that, by default, extends the `java.lang.Object` class) overrides this method, then it can take care of creating a meaningful hash code for instances of that class. This helps, among other things,  the instances of this class to be the keys in a hash table (realized using a `java.util.Hashtable` or a `java.util.HashMap`).

If you look at some of the standard library (JDK) class implementations of this method, you'll see that these classes implement this method meaningfully.

The `hashCode()` implementation of a `java.lang.Integer` class correctly chooses to just return the integer value an instance of that class represents.

The `hashCode()` implementation of a `java.lang.String` class is a little more involved and you'll find it in the source code:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

There's a lot going on here for performance (and correctness) reasons, but you can get an idea that the hash code of a string is based on the characters that the string is made of.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider `hashCode()` method of the `Object` class it is calculated by converting address of the object to integer.

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()